# Qt signals & inheritance question

Tags: qt, inheritance, subclass, signals-slots

I am relatively new to programming with Qt and had a question.  Short version:

How do I inherit signals defined in superclasses?

I am trying to subclass someone else's nicely made QTWidgets to change some of the default behavior:

```
//Plot3D is a QWidget that defines a signal "rotationChanged"
class matLinePlot : public QObject, public Plot3D {

    Q_OBJECT;
        //etc...
public:
       //etc...

        //Catch Plot3D's signal "rotationChanged" and do some magic with it:
    void initPlot(){
              QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(rotationChanged( double , double , double )),
            this, SLOT(myRotationChanged(double, double, double)));
    }
};
```

The problem is in the QObject::connect line.  What I would like to do is connect the rotationChanged SIGNAL (from qwt3D_plot.h) to a local function/SLOT - "myRotationChanged".  However whenever I do this, at run time I get:

> Object::connect: No such signal matLinePlot::rotationChanged(double, double, double)

in C:...\matrixVisualization.h.   Of course, I know that `rotationChanged` isn't in `matrixVisualization.h` - it's in `qwt_plot3D.h`, but I thought that since I inherit from `Plot3D` everything should be fine.  But, now that I think about it, since SIGNAL and SLOT are macros, I assume [MOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29#Meta_object_compiler) doesn't know/care about inheritance.

Which leads me to my question - since MOC and SIGNALS / SLOTS don't seem to know about inheritance etc: how can I subclass a widget defined somewhere else and get access to the widget's signals?

I have a lot of examples of how to use encapsulation to accomplish something like this, but I'm afraid I don't understand how to do this with inheritance.

Sorry if this is a ridiculous question - I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: the reference you see in the error to "matrixVisualization.h" shows in what file the failed QObject::connect is, not where it's trying to "look" for the matching signal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the problem is the multiple inheritance:

```
class matLinePlot : public QObject, public Plot3D
...
```

I assume that `Plot3D` is a subclass of `QObject`? In this case, you should do

```
class matLinePlot : public Plot3D
...
```

instead.

Comment: That makes things into a link error:

1>moc_matrixVisualization.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Qwt3D::Plot3D::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Plot3D@Qwt3D@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

The QT doc suggests using multiple inheritance:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/uitools-multipleinheritance.html

Although they extend QWIdget, I need QObject.

Comment: The link you posted is showing an example on how to use .ui files (those files created by Qt Designer). One important difference is that Ui::CalculatorForm is not a subclass of QObject. The rule when subclassing from QObject (and using multiple inheritance) is that only one of the superclasses can be a QObject and that the QObject has to be the first part in the inheritance.

Comment: the doc suggests multiple inheritance in a different scenario. when using Qt Designer you'll get a .ui file, then a tool called uic will take that .ui file and generate a class that's basically a translation of the .ui file, only in actual C++. so what they're basically suggesting is to inherit from that class, instead of having it as a member.

Comment: Under http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/moc.html you can find the info about multiple inheritance.

And when it comes to the compiler error, this is probably caused by a missing moc step of your header file for Plot3D.

Comment: ashcatch, this was correct.  Thanks, I did not understand the difference between the UI inheritance and the regular inheritance.

Once I linked with the moc_*.cpp and also only inherited from Plot3D this worked.

Comment: @ashcatch just updating the link (broken since Trolltech is not Qt's owner anymore): https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html

Answer (score 2):

SIGNAL(x) and SLOT(x) are macros that generate string literals.  At runtime, slots and signals are matched up using string compares of those generated literals.

(I would have added a comment to mdec's comment, but I don't have enough rep)

Comment: Right - I think that's the heart of this problem; because the string matching MACRO/MOC combo is looking in only the current header file for the signal, it doesn't know to look in my other library of compiled code.

Comment: Pete, I'm pretty sure you're wrong. The signals and slots are kept somewhere (moc generates the code for this, you can see it in the *_moc file), it has nothing to do with the current header file.

Comment: (curses! - I don't have enough rep to add to Pete's last comment about the link error)

It looks like you are not linking in moc_qwt3D_plot.cpp.

Comment: Thanks daniel and sean.  

I am linking to the qwtPlot library, and have included the .h, .cpp, and moc_*.cpp files that define the signals in my project, but still no luck. I think because the connect function is looking for matPlotLine::rotationChanged, but the actual signal has signature:
<pre>
// SIGNAL 0
void Qwt3D::Plot3D::rotationChanged(double _t1, double _t2, double _t3)
</pre>
in the moc_*.cpp file

Comment: Qwt3D is a namespace?  Is your matLinePlot in the same namespace or do you have a using directive somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I had the namespaces settled, the issue was a) the multiple inheritance and b) a linking issue - see above.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that will work if the Plot3D::rotationChanged signal is public or protected. Are you sure the signal is not private?

**Edit:**

Although I could not find a specific reference, I'll have to conclude that signals are always public. At least a test I did here seemed to indicate that I could connect to a signal even if it was declared in the private section of a class.

I also verified that a signal declared in QObject could be connected using a subclass of QObject in the connect statement so signals are definitely inheritable. As I see in other answers and comments here, the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Hi,

I tried putting a public keyword before the signal keyword, but Qt MOC did not like that:

1>MOC include\qwt3d_plot.h
1>include\qwt3d_plot.h(143): Error: Signals cannot have access specifier
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "MOC include\qwt3d_plot.h"

Comment: Oops.  Obviously I should have used "public: signals:", but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect -> see comments.

I'm using Qtopia at Uni and I believe I recall someone saying something about spacing in the SIGNAL and SLOT parameters for connect.

Try using

```
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(rotationChanged(double,double,double)),
            this, SLOT(myRotationChanged(double,double,double)));
```

I know it doesn't seem intuitive, as C++ isn't sensitive to whitespace, however I believe it has something to do with some of the magic that Qtopia/QT uses when connecting signals and slots. This may only apply to Qtopia, or I may have heard wrong, but give it a try. Additionally are the signals public or protected and have you included the appropriate header files?

Comment: I now have:
public: signals:  
    //! Emitted, if the rotation is changed
    void rotationChanged(double xAngle,double yAngle,double zAngle); 

In the header and the plotting library, and

QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(rotationChanged(double,double,double)),
  this,SLOT(myRotationChanged(double,double,double)));

In my derived class...  still same error.  I have included the header: #include <qwt3d_plot.h>  //has Plot3D class

Comment: When you declare the signals, do not declare a name for the parameter, only the types. That is 
public:

signals:
void rotationChanged(double, double, double);

 Hopefully that should fix your error.

Comment: Spacing does not effect signals & slots, what you heard is signal/slot normalization which just little-bit speeds up code but thats hardly noticable anyway.